# openCL double precision in CPU

Tags: double, opencl, cpu

Hello so I have ran several openCL kernels in double precision on GPU with the following defined:

```
#ifndef GPU_AMD
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_fp64: enable
#else
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_amd_fp64 : enable
#endif
```

And now I would like to run the same openCL kernels in double precision but on CPU instead, and am wondering if I need the extensions like above?  Or is there another openCL extension I have to enable before using double in cpu?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to use the `cl_khr_fp64` extension. The `cl_amd_fp64` extension is actually just a subset of the `cl_khr_fp64` extension for AMD GPUs.

Some AMD GPUs will actually support the full `cl_khr_fp64` extension these days, so check (with CLInfo perhaps) to see if that is a possibility.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9114039/differences-between-cl-khr-fp64-and-cl-amd-fp64) for more information.